# saber cuando se pulsa el boton dia, semana o mes en full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Buenas necesito por `javascript` o `jquery` saber si se ha pulsado o hecho clic en el botón de día semana o mes de fullcalendar.

ya el fullcalendar funciona se crea dinamicamente desde javascript agrega eventos etc.   en el hay en este momento tres botones vease en el siguiente 
fragmento;

```
header: {
         left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
         center: 'title',
         right: ''
        },
```

en si necesito que cuando se de clic ya sea en los botones :agendaDay,  agendaWeek o en month saber que se da clic porque full calendar agrega clases y no id y no se como tomar estos valores. por ejemplo con los botones siguiente y atras se puede hacer esto:

en el html :

```
<button id='next'><span  class='fc-text-arrow'><strong >›</strong></span></button>
```

en javascript:

```
$('#prev').on('click', function() {
        $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar('prev')
        actualizarComboBoxFechas(moment().day())   
    })
```

Pero con los botones de día semana y mes no sirve, en la documentación no sale nada "según lo que he leído" y por `javascript` intente esto:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fc-agendaDay-button").id="btnDia";
```

para intentar asignar id al boton del dia se agrega esto pero no dentro del elemento en especifico por lo tanto cuando pulso clic no llama a  ningún evento ojo probe con un alert("etc")

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases por la sección de [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que mejores tu pregunta, y cuéntanos que haz intentado en base a lo que solicitas, podrías ingresar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: re-formule la pregunta creo que esta mejor. igual gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 1):

Para saber cuál botón se ha pulsado puedes utilizar la clase genérica CSS que utilizan los botones de la barra y filtrar por el contenido de su texto. Este ejemplo imprimirá en la consola el texto del botón pulsado ('week','day','list','month') con lo que ya puedes filtrar

```
  $('.fc-button').click(function(e){
      console.log($(this).text())
  })
```

Y una opción alternativa y válida es agregar un evento para cada botón:

```
  $('.fc-agendaDay-button').click(function(){
        //hacer lo que debes hacer
  });
  $('.fc-agendaWeek-button').click(function(){
        //hacer lo que debes hacer
  });
  $('.fc-month-button').click(function(){
        //hacer lo que debes hacer
  });
```

En cualquiera de los dos casos debes colocar este código una vez inicializado el componente o utilizar el evento *eventAfterAllRender*

Comment: Muchas gracias nerdcoder por la solución ofrecida es lo que buscaba.   
     eventAfterAllRender: function(){
                        $('.fc-button').click(function(e){
                            console.log($(this).text())
                        })
                    }

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @ErwisÁlvarez? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0):

Según la librería de `FullCalendar`, esa es la forma correcta de obtener el día, mes y año dependiendo del día al que le des `click`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log(date.month()); //day of the week: 1 for monday
        console.log(date.get('date')); //day of month: 20 for today
        console.log(date.year());
     }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Tiene su función llamada `dayClick` que es la que se encarga de todo.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Ojo Ricardo que desea saber cuál botón ha pulsado el usuario de la barra de botones dia, semana o mes, no los días del calendario

Comment: Gracias por responder Ricardo. pero la observación de nerdcoder es apropiada. igual la respuesta de abajo de nerdcoder me ha funcionado. Gracias y feliz día.